"DBPROCESS is dead or not enabled" error in Cloud Run when writing to specific on-prem table
I am trying to store data that I compute on a cloud run instance to our on-premises SQL Server database but I am get errors:

Pymssql: DBPROCESS is dead or not enabled

Setup
There is a VPN tunnel connecting the VPC in Google Cloud and the on-premises SQL Server.
I am using SQLModel and pymssql to orchestrate the DB connection.
The below code block shows the key aspects of how I am managing the connection
class MsSQLInterface:

    # Init part is left out

    @property
    def _connection_string(self) -> str:
        return f"mssql+pymssql://{self.db_user}:{self.db_pass}@{self.db_server}:{self.db_port}/{self.db_name}"

    @cached_property
    def _engine(self):
        try:
            return create_engine(
                self._connection_string, echo=False, connect_args={"timeout": 60}, pool_pre_ping=True
            )
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"{e!s}")
            raise Exception from e
     
    # This is the method I use to write data
    def write(self, data: Payload) -> int:
         
         #This method splits the Payload into batches and then stores each batch
         #separately. Everything but the db-related parts were left out for the 
         #sake of brevity.

             with Session(self._engine) as session:
                try:
                    session.bulk_save_objects(data_to_insert)
                    session.commit()
                except OperationalError as e:
                   # handle exception...

Symptoms
The amount of data is quite large so I am storing it in batches. When writing data to a specific table after a couple of batches I start getting the following error:

(pymssql.exceptions.OperationalError) (20047, b'DB-Lib error message 20003, severity 6:
Adaptive Server connection timed out
DB-Lib error message 20047, severity 9:
DBPROCESS is dead or not enabled')

It occurs quite randomly at first, but after a couple of reruns of this job, I get stuck in a situation where first 3 batches get processed all right, but any following requests fail.
Based on the symptoms, I would think that it might be caused by

Random connection drop-outs.
The requests hitting some firewall, as suggested here

But: if it was just an unstable connection, I would assume that after some time I would be able to store the data and the drop-outs would not last minutes, and result in consecutive requests failing. Also, when I try to run another job that writes data to a different table, it runs without problems. This is also why I am not sure this can be caused by some firewall settings, since running another job that writes to a different table on the same server, using the same VPN tunnel works fine.
What I have tried

increasing engine timeout
setting pool_pre_ping=True as suggested here
implementing random (short) delay before each request
implementing simple random backoff retry strategy. This sometimes helps and I am able to recover from the error and process a couple more batches but never all of them.

Any ideas on what to try or what might be the cause are more than welcome. Thank you!

Try pyodbc instead of pymssql, it is the officially supported library nowadays

Thank you for the quick comment! Indeed, swapping pymssql for pyodbc seems to have helped. I will keep an eye on it but if no errors show up I will consider it solved!
